# Whitelist my App in logcat / chatty identical 1 line

Tags: android, android-studio, logging, logcat

Logcat is filtering my logs, so I get only:

```
1234-1234/com.example.test I/chatty: uid=45678(com.example.test) identical 1 line
```

This is a serious issue for me, I tried applying the solutions suggested in other threads like

```
adb logcat -P ""
```

I also read the documentation (`logcat --help` and the "-P" option at [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/logcat.html#filteringOutput) like `adb logcat -P 45678`), but this also didn't help.

`adb logcat -p` shows that I whitelisted my app:

```
adb logcat -p
45678 (the UID of my app)
```

Still the logs are getting filtered. How can I fix that? I simply want no log filtering on my app during development.

Answer (score 0):

My fault. I checked in Android Studio where I had the log leve filter set to "Info". The chatty message is "info" level, my log messages were "verbose" level. Actually I am getting both, my app log messages and the chatty messages...
Make sure to test without Android Studio using logcat: `adb logcat` and see if you see your log message. If that works, something is selected wrong in Android Studio like it was for me and by me.